# how to execute a python script in SCADE?

Tags: python

This is a python script for the function switch and delay, but I have problem in the execution of the script in [SCADE](https://github.com/openETCS/model-evaluation/wiki/SCADE-Description). Please, how can I execute this script in SCADE ?

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

L=[[1,2],[6,13],[20,23],[25,35],[38,45]]

def tem(L):
    S=[]

    for i in L:
        if i[1]-i[0]>=5:
            S.append([i[0]+5,i[1]])
    return S

def shape(S):
    M=[]

    for i in range(0,S[-1][-1]+1):
        s=0
        for j in S:
            if i>=j[0]  and i<=j[1]:
                s=s+1
        M.append(s)

    return M

plt.plot(shape(L))
plt.plot(shape(tem(L)))
plt.show()            

print(shape(L))
```

Comment: A more up to date link for SCADE is at [ANSYS](https://www.ansys.com/products/embedded-software/ansys-scade-suite), but I don't get _any_ impression at all of what sort of API if anything is available, either from the page you link to or the one I found.

Comment: And I removed the language tags that I just couldn't see how they related.

Comment: Please how can I convert this python script to tcl sript